# Swap partition not active

Tags: fstab, swap, partitioning, cryptsetup, cryptswap

My swap partition is neither mounted nor active.
My system does find/recognise the swap partition but that is it

My `fstab` entries:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=13d93751-743e-49f4-9cd4-681aeaa2ba30 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=8CB4-46F0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
#UUID=5b41eeb7-0447-491e-b0ce-8f3d35280ea2 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
#PARTUUID=778e6277-6364-11e3-9faa-0c54a54d3e5a
 /media/ntfs -ntfs-3g ntfs defaults,umask=222  0 0
```

I have inserted the last UUID manually into the fstab to access an external NTFS disk. Could that be the issue?

As requested here is my `crypttab`:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=5b41eeb7-0447-491e-b0ce-8f3d35280ea2 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

And here my `lsblk -f`

```
NAME           FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sr0                                                              
sda                                                              
├─sda4         ext4         0d497413-33f4-4147-83e1-158673893393 /home
├─sda2         ext4         13d93751-743e-49f4-9cd4-681aeaa2ba30 /
├─sda3         swap         5b41eeb7-0447-491e-b0ce-8f3d35280ea2 
│ └─cryptswap1 swap         4cd2e69a-b27e-41e1-9250-3d2e65ebbf11 [SWAP]
└─sda1         vfat         8CB4-46F0                            /boot/efi
```

The command `sudo swapon -a` does not give me any output at all!

The command `ls -lA /dev/mapper` shows

```
control
cryptswap1
```

The command `swapon` shows

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-0 partition 3,9G   0B   -1
```

Output of `systemctl status systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service`

```
● systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service - Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/crypttab; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sa 2016-12-24 10:37:43 CET; 36min ago
     Docs: man:crypttab(5)
           man:systemd-cryptsetup-generator(8)
           man:systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8)
  Process: 919 ExecStartPost=/sbin/mkswap /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 702 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach cryptswap1 /dev/disk/by-uuid/5b41eeb7-0447-491e-b0ce-8f3d35280ea2 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 702 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dez 24 10:37:37 dirksson-SATELLITE-PRO-C50-A-1J1 systemd[1]: Starting Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1...
Dez 24 10:37:38 dirksson-SATELLITE-PRO-C50-A-1J1 systemd-cryptsetup[702]: Set cipher aes, mode xts-plain64, key size 256 bits for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/5b41eeb7-0447-491e-b0ce-8f3d35280ea2.
Dez 24 10:37:43 dirksson-SATELLITE-PRO-C50-A-1J1 mkswap[919]: Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 3,9 GiB (4163366912 bytes)
Dez 24 10:37:43 dirksson-SATELLITE-PRO-C50-A-1J1 mkswap[919]: no label, UUID=eb58cf21-d0aa-41c2-bd86-a81466328f93
Dez 24 10:37:43 dirksson-SATELLITE-PRO-C50-A-1J1 systemd[1]: Started Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1.
```

`free -h` shows

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3,7G        975M        1,7G        108M        1,0G        2,4G
Swap:          3,9G          0B        3,9G
```

`swapon -h` shows no entry for cryptswap

```
/dev/sda3                               partition   4066300 0   -2
```

Comment: You've got a cryptswap. Can you please [edit] your question and add the content of `/etc/crypttab`?

Comment: Okay, looks good so far. What does `lsblk -f` show? What does `ls -lA /dev/mapper` show? What does `sudo swapon -a` output? Oh, and please leave me a comment with "@ByteCommander" so that I get notified once you have edited and updated your question.

Comment: I remember problems with cryptswap in previous versions of Ubuntu. But the current 16.04.1 LTS should work well. Which version are you running?

Comment: I still can not see a problem, unfortunately. However, I believe `sudo swapon -a` should have printed an error message if it was unable to turn on the configured swaps. The virtual crypt disk is also there. Can you please run plain `swapon` and recheck whether the swap is really not activated? Also please show the output of `systemctl status systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service  | cat`. Have you rebooted since setting the swap up or doing the last changes? If not, do that.

Comment: @ByteCommander yes I have rebooted but no change...

Comment: Sorry, to me it looks like it works. What does `free -h` tell you?

Comment: @ByteCommander updated!

Comment: Your swap is working just fine. What do you want?? I'm voting to close this question as not reproducible.

Comment: Does `swapon -s` show an entry for `/dev/mapper/cryptswap`? If not, what *does* it show instead?

Comment: @ByteCommander   ok maybe it just looked like it doesnt... I am a newbie..

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have updated the info, David.

Comment: The various file and command listings are quite inconsistent and suggest that *something* (probably you assuming an at least moderately sane system setup) changed the swap configuration in between them. Could you please 1) reboot your system, 2) re-run *all of the commands* and 3) replace the old listings in your question with their new versions so we might come to a conclusion based on consistent facts? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster is right, the last output of `swapon -h` (although at least my `swapon` does not have a `-h` option, no idea what that's supposed to do or why it works at all) is not consistent with the stuff you showed us before and says that you're using `/dev/sda3` as raw swap partition and not as encrypted one. I reopened the question. As David said, please reboot and rerun all the commands and update the outputs in your question, then notify us with a comment when you're done. Thanks.